# After executing "adb logcat", Why the status of device becam "offline"

Tags: android, adb

I'm using the Android13 on Pixel5, and I meet a question that every time I execute the command "adb logcat", the status of the device became "offline". I tried the same "adb" on Pixel2 Android10. The problem did not arise.

[picture of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrvg.png)

I've tried everything I found on the Internet, like setting USB options and changing the "adb" to the latest version, but all of them cannot fix the problem.

I really don't have any clue what's going on.

Comment: Do other adb commands like `adb shell` work?

Comment: YES, but if I execute "logcat" in adb shell, the device status will also become "offline".

Comment: You can try to execute `adb shell`and then `logcat`. May be you see an error message if something goes wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem after I cleaned the logcat buffer, thank you